# getch() equating carriage return to esc key

Tags: c, dos, turbo-c++, bgi, getch

I'm writing a program to reset a password, and I am having some issues with escaping the program before the final (accept new password) condition is made. I am using conio.h's getch() function to accept input to write it to a string (using string.h)

I'm using Borland TurboC++ V4.0 to keep compatibility, as this is add-on code to an old MS DOS program. I would use a more current ide/compiler if I could.

This is a small snippet of the program; I have left out the headers and the new password/check password lines as they function atm. I am very new to C programming, I am aware this is probably not the easiest way to write, and there is a lot of redundancy. I have tried creating a flag to exit the program, as well as a break function, and they both run into the same problem; they treat '\r' as esc and vise versa.

```
main()
{
char password[] = "0000000000000000000";
char newpassword[] = "0000000000000000000";
char checkpassword[] = "0000000000000000000";
char answer[] = "hrigsetup";
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C://TC//BGI");

//draw screen
rectangle(0,0,screen_x,screen_y);
rectangle(screen_x/4,screen_y/3,(3*(screen_x/4)),(2*(screen_y/3)));
rectangle(((screen_x/4)+50),((screen_y/3)+45),(3*(screen_x/4)-50),((screen_y/3)+20));
rectangle(((screen_x/4)+50),((screen_y/3)+90),(3*(screen_x/4)-50),((screen_y/3)+65));
rectangle(((screen_x/4)+50),((screen_y/3)+135),(3*(screen_x/4)-50),((screen_y/3)+110));

//write text
setcolor(headercolor);
settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,2);
settextjustify(CENTER_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
outtextxy(screen_x/2,((screen_y/4)),"Change Password");
setcolor(drawcolor);
settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
settextjustify(LEFT_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
outtextxy((screen_x/2)-108,((screen_y/2)-70),"Enter Old Password");
outtextxy((screen_x/2)-108,((screen_y/2)-25),"Enter New Password");
outtextxy((screen_x/2)-108,((screen_y/2)+20),"Re-Enter New Password");


//enter old password
//password entry
while(unlock != 1 && esc_key != 1)
{
    while((password[p] = getch()) != '\r')                                          //mask text logic
    {
        if(password[p] == '\b')                                                 //tolerate a backspace
        {
            if(p == 17 && endchar == 0)                                     //Logic password field
            {                                                               //bounds/overflow protection
                password[p] = ' ';
                setcolor(clear);
                settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
                settextjustify(LEFT_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
                outtextxy((screen_x/2)-(100-(p*8)),(screen_y/2)-50,"Û");
                endchar = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                password[p] = ' ';
                setcolor(clear);
                settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
                settextjustify(LEFT_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
                outtextxy((screen_x/2)-(100-((p-1)*8)),(screen_y/2)-50,"Û");
                p--;
                if(p <= -1)
                    p = 0;
            }
        }
            else if(password[p] == 27 )          //esc logic
            {                                  //have tried 27, 0x1b, '\027
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(clear_bar == 1)                                            //erase contents of password
            {                                                             //box
                setcolor(clear);
                settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,3);
                outtextxy((screen_x/2)-2,(screen_y/2)-59,"ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ");
                setcolor(drawcolor);
                settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
                settextjustify(LEFT_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
                clear_bar = 0;
            }
            setcolor(drawcolor);
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
            settextjustify(LEFT_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);
            outtextxy((screen_x/2)-(100-(p*8)),(screen_y/2)-50,"*");
            if(p == 17)
            {
                p = 17;
                endchar = 0;
            }
            else
                p++;

        }
    }
    if(strcmp(password, answer) !=0 && esc_key != 1)                                    //check password = wrong,
    {                                                                   //clear password box, fill
        setcolor(headercolor);                                      //read and write "incorrect"
        settextjustify(CENTER_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);                       //in the box, write "Try Again"
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,3);                     //below input box
        outtextxy((screen_x/2)-2,(screen_y/2)-59,"ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ");
        setcolor(drawcolor);
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
        outtextxy(screen_x/2,(screen_y/2)-50,"Incorrect");
        outtextxy(screen_x/2,(screen_y/2)+100,"Try Again");
        unlock = 0;
        clear_bar = 1;
        newp_ent = 0;
        password[p] = 0;
        p = 0;


    }
    if(strcmp(password, answer) == 0 && esc_key != 1)                                //check password = correct
    {                                                                // clear and fill input box
        setcolor(unlock_color);                                  //green and display "Correct"
        settextjustify(CENTER_TEXT,TOP_TEXT);                    //write "Press Any Key" below
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,3);                  //the input box
        outtextxy((screen_x/2)-2,(screen_y/2)-59,"ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ");
        setcolor(clear);
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
        outtextxy(screen_x/2,(screen_y/2)+100,"ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ");
        setcolor(drawcolor);
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,1);
        outtextxy(screen_x/2,(screen_y/2)-50,"Correct");
        unlock = 1;
        newp_ent = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this line, at line 87 of the posted code: `                p = 17;` does absolutely nothing as the prior `if` already proved that 'p' is already equal to 17

Comment: there are a lot of 'magic' numbers in the code.  Strongly suggest (and you will appreciate this as you perform the maintenance) that all such numbers be #define'd with meaningful names and then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: Please, for readability and clarity of the code, consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  Never use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggest 4 spaces as that is visible, even with variable width fonts

Comment: in this code block: ` else if(password[p] == 27 )          //esc logic
        {                                  //have tried 27, 0x1b, '\027
            break;
        }`  it seems the variable: `esc_key` needs to be set to 1, because that is tested later, after the while loop

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but I do not see where the `password` char array is ever terminated with a '\0'.  The result will be the call to `strcmp()` will fail to make a proper/successful comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a line missing fom the code block which detects the Esc key. You have detected it but not set the flag you have for this purpose.

```
else if(password[p] == 27 )
{
    esc_key = 1;            // <-- add this line
    break;
}
```

Comment: sorry, the esc_key variable is a flag i tried using when the break function did not work for me. I was using it to make all of the while loops false if it was active so it would skip to the end of the program. It had the same problem as using break, it would end the program when enter was hit. I forgot to pull out the flag from the while functions before I posted.

Comment: I ran (a version of) your code, and adding this line made it behave.

Comment: You are correct, I just tried it. Misunderstood the break function, without it it was making it behave unpredictably. Thank you!